# ¿como hacer una pausa en un evento de click en java?

Tags: java

cree una interfaz con varios Jframe que es un juego para enseñar los colores a niños, cuando se abre la ventana te salta un audio del personaje diciendo el color y cuando seleccionas un color incorrecto sale otro audio y cambia el texto a lo que dice el personaje
hasta ahi perfecto pero al momento de seleccionar el color correcto no se como hacer una pequeña pausa para que suene el audio y cambie el texto de la caja antes de que pase a la nueva ventana

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver intente hacerlo con un Thread.sleep pero creo que esto no es lo mas adecuado

Comment: Si tienes una imagen con código, ponlo _como texto, con formato_. [Subir código como imagen es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

no me queda muy claro, pero por lo que veo deberias de quitar el try catch y poner el sleep despues de llamar al metodo
cosmico.reproducir();
Thread.sleep(2000);